# Where does Postman get installed in macOS?

Tags: macos, postman

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and have been using Postman (8.9.1) for quite sometime now (I run it by clicking Applications -> Postman from Finder).

I'm curious to find out if I can invoke Postman from terminal and so, where exactly is it installed? I can see the config files etc… are stored under `/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/Postman`.

But, exactly in which location is Postman installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the /Applications folder, and from the terminal try

```
open /Applications/Postman.app
```

Then try `open` with a few other file types and see what happens.